# NiFi - Call Rest API for every row in the file

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a datset of IDs, I've got a flow file that has one row per ID. I have an API that takes this ID as a parameter, and I want to harvest the results for all rows back into NiFi (example below).

```
https://service.com/api/thing/{ID}
```

How in NiFi, can I call this API, for all IDs in my dataset. Ideally using some parallelism if possible.

(for reference, in SSIS I could load these IDs into an array and then loop over an API call with a parameter for the ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `SplitText` to get each Id as a `flowfile`
[image]

Then copy content to an attribute by `ExtractText` . add custom property such as 'message.body'  in this example

[image]

so that `ExtractText` would add message.body.0 attribute to the flowfile and you can use it `InvokeHttp` like below . Please note that since your endpoint is `https` , you may need to configure `SSL Contect Service`

[image]

Finally , you can set concurent task count for each `Processor` for parallelism

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I needed to get me thinking in the correct paradigm.